# Can't connect to database - The specific error code is 1006

Tags: sql-server, connections

Yesterday I entered data into databases - it was several million records. Everything went ok, I was happy. But today, when I want to connect to the database, I get this error.[image: Error notice]

The problem now is that I can't login to the test database - do you know how to solve this problem? Thank you for any advice.

I found some instructions to check if the windows backup and volume shadow copy services are running. Volume shadow copy service is running but I don't have windows backup.

Comment: Have you got any kind of backup? VM snapshot? SQL Server backup? SAN snapshot? Anything?

Comment: I have a backup from the other day, do you think it will be necessary to restore the database?