# Can't connect to database - The specific error code is 1006

Tags: sql-server

Yesterday I entered data into databases - it was several million records. Everything went ok, I was happy.
But today, when I want to connect to the database, I get this error.[image: Error].

The problem now is that I can't login to the test database - do you know how to solve this problem?
Thank you for any advice.

I found some instructions to check if the windows backup and volume shadow copy services are running.
Volume shadow copy service is running but I don't have windows backup.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: This, however, doesn't look to be on topic for [so]. [dba.se] would likely be a better place, but they also don't like images of error messages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't connect to database - The specific error code is 1006](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/328327/cant-connect-to-database-the-specific-error-code-is-1006)